# DIT write access for cn=config or LDAPI

Tags: openldap

I have an OpenLDAP 2.4 setup with multiple DITs.
Each DIT database has a RootDN with manage rights, as it should. I need to give manage rights [or at least write] to either cn=config, or LDAPI so that there would be OpenLDAP "root" able to manage both config database, as well as individual DIT databases.

I have tried various olcAccess configurations, and nothing worked. Basically, I tried two general approaches - messing config ACLs as well as adding cn=config to individual DITs ACLs as below:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com" write
  by dn="cn=config" write
  by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base=""
  by * read
olcAccess: {2}to *
  by self write
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com" write
  by * read
```

Nothing has worked so far. I have been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com" write by dn="cn=config" write by * read
```

Comment: Try adding some explanation of what this does, and why it solves your problem.